# Javascript / jQuery design question re: performance

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any performance / memory hit differential among the three following styles?

Exhibit A:

```
var func = function() {
    // do some magic
}

$("#div").somePlugin({someEvent: func});
```

Exhibit B:

```
$("#div").somePlugin({someEvent: function() {
    // do some magic
});
```

Exhibit C:

```
function func() {
    // do some magic
}

$("#div").somePlugin({someEvent: func});
```

Comment: You should not drastically change the question once posted :)

Comment: "drastically" is a bit much, innit?

Comment: Yes, actually, the first vs the third has more implications and changes the cope of the question.

Comment: @Nick Well let's see an awesome response that blows minds!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a little, slightly (really slightly) better performance for the function expression:

```
var func = function(){
};
```

That is a such called `function expression`. The otherside, the `function statement` is your third example:

```
function func(){
}
```

Function statements are converted internally into function expressions by `ECMA-/Javascript`, so thats the reason why it might(!) be slighty faster, but really, nothing to worry about.

Your **B:** example shows an `anonymous function`, which also has no performance impact over the **A** and **C**.

Answer (score 0):

There's no performance hit to speak of, it's more of a re-use/style thing, I'd say.  In both A and C, the `func` becomes reusable, which can be helpful in certain situations.  With B, you encapsulate functionality which is often desirable.

I prefer C as it's cleaner to read and enabled reuse without refactoring.